# jQuery Tablesorter sort

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I am using the Tablesorter plugin for jQuery and I have it sorting a merchandise stock table. It is working fine, but I would like to change the way it sorts and can't figure it out.

For the QTY column, the data is either a number for how much of an item is in stock, or if an item is not in stock it could be "out" or "special order". The way it sorts the QTY column descending now is "out" then the highest number to lowest. I would like the words to be last because if QTY is not a number it will always equal 0.

Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: include relevent code?

Comment: Maybe you can accomplish this with a custom parser http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html

Comment: Custom parsers will work perfect! I don't know how how missed that, Thank-you. If you want to post as an answer I'll give you credit

Answer (score 1):

Just found that the new version of tablesorter includes this functionality (since version 2.0.10).
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-digits-strings.html